# PHP SESSION Array only storing in index 0

Tags: php, session

Hey guys this is the code I am using

```
$ch="s1";
$_SESSION[$ch] = array();
$_SESSION[$ch][] = $_POST['t0'];
$_SESSION[$ch][] = $_POST['t1'];
$_SESSION[$ch][] = $_POST['t2'];
$_SESSION[$ch][] = $_POST['t3'];
$_SESSION[$ch][] = $_POST['t4'];
$_SESSION[$ch][] = $_POST['t5'];
$_SESSION[$ch][] = $_POST['t6'];
```

But when I am printing the session data on screen `$_SESSION['s1'][0]` is having all the data of all the other index, `$_SESSION['s1'][1]` to `$_SESSION['s1'][6]` are not displaying anything.

Here is the result for `var_dump($_SESSION)`;

```
's1' => array (size=7) 
   0 => string 'All Purpose Horn Anvil A-1t1=Shipping Weight: 900gmst2=Price: € 5.00t3=Quantity: t4= t5=56t6=All Purpose Horn Anvil A-1 Shipping Weight: 900gms Price: € 5.00 Quantity: 56' (length=192) 
    1 => null 
    2 => null 
    3 => null 
    4 => null 
    5 => null 
    6 => null
```

For some reason the POST indexes i.e t0 to t6 are been shown in s1.

Comment: Post the result of `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: Done, I don't know why all the Post data are getting appended to the first index.

Comment: it would be nice if you could mark an answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Actually none of the replies are answering my question, it was a mistake in jquery which I posted below as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a mistake in passing data to POST. 
In Jquery I was using this without the "&" between the variables, that was causing the problem.

```
var dataString = 't0=' + txt[0]+ '&t1='+ txt[1] + '&t2='+ txt[2] + '&t3='+ txt[3] + '&t4='+ txt[4] + '&t5='+ txt[5] + '&t6='+ temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Propably you overwrite that data in other place or just do a mistake in printing.

```
$ch="s1";
$_SESSION[$ch] = array();
$_SESSION[$ch][] = mt_rand(1,200);
$_SESSION[$ch][] = mt_rand(1,200);
$_SESSION[$ch][] = mt_rand(1,200);
$_SESSION[$ch][] = mt_rand(1,200);
$_SESSION[$ch][] = mt_rand(1,200);
$_SESSION[$ch][] = mt_rand(1,200);
$_SESSION[$ch][] = mt_rand(1,200);
print_r( $_SESSION );
```

Output:

> Array ( [s1] => Array ( [0] => 158 [1] => 145 [2] => 110 [3] => 139
>   [4] => 153 [5] => 183 [6] => 51 ) )

Comment: I don't understand, please give details.

Comment: The problem is not in code fragment that you have posted - the problem is in other place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a dot before equal:

```
    $ch="s1";
    $_SESSION[$ch] = array();

    $_SESSION[$ch][] .= $_POST['t0'];
    $_SESSION[$ch][] .= $_POST['t1'];
    $_SESSION[$ch][] .= $_POST['t2'];
    $_SESSION[$ch][] .= $_POST['t3'];
    $_SESSION[$ch][] .= $_POST['t4'];
    $_SESSION[$ch][] .= $_POST['t5'];
    $_SESSION[$ch][] .= $_POST['t6'];
```

You can see this code working on this link ([3v4l.org/8ZDi9](http://3v4l.org/8ZDi9)):

```
<?php

    $ch="s1";
    $_SESSION[$ch] = array();

    $_SESSION[$ch][] .= 11;
    $_SESSION[$ch][] .= 22;

    var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: This seems to be wrong, empty [] means array_push (bit optimized one).
There is no item to concatenate with in this moment.

Comment: It will work if you have suppressed error reporting, because you concatenate 11 to undefined variable. PHP will allow you to do so, but however it cannot help the guy question, it will act the same way as without the `.`.

Comment: This also turns the integers into strings.

Comment: I would bet on `$str = (string) $integer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch="s1";
$_SESSION[$ch] = array();
$_SESSION[$ch][0] = $_POST['t0'];
$_SESSION[$ch][1] = $_POST['t1'];
$_SESSION[$ch][2] = $_POST['t2'];
$_SESSION[$ch][3] = $_POST['t3'];
$_SESSION[$ch][4] = $_POST['t4'];
$_SESSION[$ch][6] = $_POST['t5'];
$_SESSION[$ch][7] = $_POST['t6'];
```

Or better

```
$ch="s1";
$_SESSION[$ch] = array();


for ($i=0; $i<=6; $i++)
{
   $_SESSION[$ch][$i] = $_POST['t'.$i];
}
```

Comment: Fix this row: $_SESSION[$ch][6] = $_POST['t5'];